# Calculating the start of a new month in SF

Tags: formula, process-builder, workflow, date, field-update

So essentially what I'm looking for is to be able to calculate the start of a new month. So for context, there is a checkbox that I want to clear at the start of every new month (if it's ticked ofc). So new month starts, all records where that box is ticked are now unticked...

Is this something that's doable, or even worth the effort?

*Any Answers Appreciated :)*

Answer (score 0):

So you have many options to do so but I suggest the below -

Write a batch class to do this operation and schedule it on the 1st of every month using corn expression.

So your job runs on the 1st of every month and checks and fetches records that are checked and will reset them to false.

Steps are -
First Create a batch class that says (ResetField) this batch class contains the logic to fetch the checked records and then mark them as unchecked and then create a Scheduler for this job that says (FieldResetSceduler).

```
global class FieldResetSceduler implements Schedulable {
   global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
      ResetField b = new ResetField(); 
      database.executebatch(b);
   }
}
```

Use the below CRON in the Developer Console -

```
Developer Console > Debug > Open Execute Anonymous Window > paste the below code > Execute

FieldResetSceduler fRS = new FieldResetSceduler();
String sch = '0 0 0 1 * ? *';
String jobID = system.schedule('Monthly Reset Field Job', sch, frs);
```

This will solve the above use case.

Comment: Thank you, will give this a try

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be with [scheduled flows](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/record-triggered-flows/add-a-scheduled-task-to-your-flow).

You can set the flow schedule to run daily and then use a decision element to check if it's the first of the month. You can do this by creating a formula to check if DAY(TODAY()) = 1.

A scheduled flow makes it easy to process only the records where your condition is met (i.e. your checkbox is selected). It also runs on a record by record basis, which simplifies the data logic.

I'd suggest you try working through the linked trailhead to get a feel for how that works.